# How can I calculate the difference in weeks between two dates in VB.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

At the moment, all my results return '0'.

What am I doing wrong?

If it helps, the current code creates a datatable from a SQL command query, and then looks at each row individually to get the difference for each Date.

Current code:

> ```
>     Dim Con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=ApplicationData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
>     Con.Open() 'Open the connection
>     Dim strCommand As String = "SELECT fDateAdded, fName FROM Films"
>
>     Dim SQL As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strCommand, Con)
>     Dim DataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL)
>     Dim DataTable As New DataTable("Films") ' Create a new data table structure
>     DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) ' Fill the data table structure from the information in the database.
>
>     For Each row As DataRow In DataTable.Rows
>         MessageBox.Show(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, row.Item("fDateAdded"), Now))
>     Next row
>
>     Con.Close()
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to cast your date as a DATE....

```
MessageBox.Show(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CDate(row.Item("fDateAdded")), Now)
```

Also I've not tried it but have a go at using DateInterval.WeekOfYear this may give you the difference in weeks but this could possible be anything up to 6 days out. Need some testing to see results.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use "w" or dateinterval.weekday

```
MessageBox.Show(DateDiff(DateInterval.weekDay, CDate(row.Item("fDateAdded")), Now)
```

Or

```
MessageBox.Show(DateDiff("w", CDate(row.Item("fDateAdded")), Now)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx